# Vectors and Matrices

Tags: vector, matrix

i've got a little question about vectors and matrices in the programming world.
I read a lot of articles when people used vector/matrices for saying arrays.
I can understand the "why" of matrices, because they are like an imaginary table with rows and columns and then they can be compared to multi-dimensinal arrays.
But i cannot explain to me the similarity between a one-dimension array and a vector.
Vector is a thing which have a directory and a magnutude, representable by an arrow, then why compare it to a one-dimension array, which is a collection of scalable values?

I read about a recent vulnerabilty in the yahoo toolbar

*Any one using Y! Toolbar could simply get their Yahoo, Google, Youtube, and other services hijacked by visiting any of those websites containing an XSS vector. Since these are highly reputable websites, it makes it easier for attackers to hijack accounts due to the fact that reputation and websites that contains a malicious code designed for an attack*

I know what XSS is, but a XSS vector... oh my god, no idea.

Regards

Comment: The use of the word "vector" when referring to a security vulnerability is a different use than the use of the word when referring to a data structure.  The word means two different things in those contexts.

Comment: "Vector is a thing which have a directory and a magnutude, representable by an arrow" <- No. A vector is an element of a vector space.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i was too general. Then what does mean a vector referring to a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction and magnitude of a vector can be described in the form of coordinates of the end point of the vector when the start of the vector is at the origin.  When expressing a vector as a one dimensional array, the elements of the array are the coordinates of the end point of the vector.

With respect to security vulnerabilities, the use of the word is a bit different:  there, the "vector" is the way security is bypassed.  It's related only in the sense that the "vector" for a security vulnerability can metaphorically be thought of as kind of an arrow getting past the security measures.